# Bootstrap 5 footer is overlapping the renderbody in MVC app

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, footer

I know this seems to be a common issue - but I just cant get it to work!
I recently (stupidly) renamed my bootstrap.css file, as I had introduced a new one (from bootswatch).  My render body content now overlaps the footer (even though I have re-renamed the bootstrap.css file.  Everything else seems to work OK. I am using Bootstrap v5.1.0

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Suplizer</title>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Suplizer.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   @* <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/pulse.css" />*@
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Suplizer</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Suppliers" asp-action="Index">Suppliers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Documents" asp-action="Index">Documents</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Questions" asp-action="Index">Questions</a>
                        </li>
                        @*<li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="SupplierQuestions" asp-action="Index">Supplier Questions</a>
                        </li>*@
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    

    

        <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - Suplizer - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>


    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my layout file
Thanks in advance for any help
Reading other solutions - I have tried...

1. Removing the reference to the site.css file in the layout file
2. Using the new bootstrap swatch
3. Putting  around the footer

Answer (score 0):

```css
#footer{background: #404040;padding: 0 0 30px 0;color: #fff;font-size: 14px}#footer .footer-newsletter{padding: 50px 0;background: #404040}#footer .footer-newsletter h4{font-size: 24px;margin: 0 0 20px 0;padding: 0;line-height: 1;font-weight: 600}#footer .footer-newsletter form{margin-top: 30px;background: #fff;padding: 6px 10px;position: relative;border-radius: 50px}#footer .footer-newsletter form input[type="email"]{border: 0;padding: 8px;width: calc(100% - 140px)}#footer .footer-newsletter form input[type="submit"]{position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;border: 0;background: none;font-size: 16px;padding: 0 30px;margin: 3px;background: #e96b56;color: #fff;transition: 0.3s;border-radius: 50px}#footer .footer-newsletter form input[type="submit"]:hover{background: #e6573f}#footer .footer-top{background: #3b3b3b;border-top: 1px solid #474747;border-bottom: 1px solid #474747;padding: 60px 0 30px 0}#footer .footer-top .footer-info{margin-bottom: 30px}#footer .footer-top .footer-info h3{font-size: 18px;margin: 0 0 20px 0;padding: 2px 0 2px 0;line-height: 1;font-weight: 700}#footer .footer-top .footer-info p{font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;margin-bottom: 0;font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;color: #fff}#footer .footer-top .social-links a{font-size: 18px;display: inline-block;background: #545454;color: #fff;line-height: 1;padding: 8px 0;margin-right: 4px;border-radius: 50%;text-align: center;width: 36px;height: 36px;transition: 0.3s}#footer .footer-top .social-links a:hover{background: #e96b56;color: #fff;text-decoration: none}#footer .footer-top h4{font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;color: #fff;text-transform: uppercase;position: relative;padding-bottom: 12px}#footer .footer-top .footer-links{margin-bottom: 30px}#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul{list-style: none;padding: 0;margin: 0}#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul i{padding-right: 2px;color: #ec7f6d;font-size: 18px;line-height: 1}#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul li{padding: 10px 0;display: flex;align-items: center}#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul li:first-child{padding-top: 0}#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul a{color: #fff;transition: 0.3s;display: inline-block;line-height: 1}#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul a:hover{color: #e96b56}#footer .footer-top .footer-contact{margin-bottom: 30px}#footer .footer-top .footer-contact p{line-height: 26px}#footer .copyright{text-align: center;padding-top: 30px}#footer .credits{padding-top: 10px;text-align: center;font-size: 13px;color: #fff}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer id="footer"> <div class="footer-newsletter"> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-lg-6"> <h4>Our Newsletter</h4> <p>Tamen quem nulla quae legam multos aute sint culpa legam noster magna</p> </div> <div class="col-lg-6"> <form action="" method="post"> <input type="email" name="email"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe"> </form> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="footer-top"> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links"> <h4>Useful Links</h4> <ul> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Home</a></li> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">About us</a></li> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Services</a></li> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Terms of service</a></li> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li> </ul> </div> <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links"> <h4>Our Services</h4> <ul> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Web Design</a></li> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Web Development</a></li> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Product Management</a></li> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Marketing</a></li> <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li> </ul> </div> <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-contact"> <h4>Contact Us</h4> <p> A108 Adam Street <br> New York, NY 535022<br> United States <br><br> <strong>Phone:</strong> +1 5589 55488 55<br> <strong>Email:</strong> info@example.com<br> </p> </div> <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-info"> <h3>About DevVE</h3> <p>Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat lide par naso tierra. Justo eget nada terra videa magna derita valies darta donna mare fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus.</p> <div class="social-links mt-3"> <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></a> <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a> <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a> <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="container"> <div class="copyright"> &copy; Copyright <strong><span>DevVE</span></strong>. All Rights Reserved </div> <div class="credits"> Designed by <a href="#">SalvadorDevVE</a> </div> </div>
</footer>
```

Try this out - [Bootstrap 5 Footer](https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-5-footer-bootstrap-5-75679937#)